# How to run Java application from Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I have a Java application that does something like:

```
public class MyApplication {
    public static int main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(System.getProperty("my.property"));
    }
}
```

How do I call this from Groovy such that the Groovy script sets the System property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call Java with the `-D` command line parameter:

```
def output = "java -Dmy.property=foo MyApplication".execute().text
```

Alternatively, you can call the Java class from within your script without starting a new Java process:

```
System.properties['my.property'] = 'foo'
MyApplication.main([] as String[])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a java application in eclipse IDE. IDE is installed with groovy plugin. To run this java application in groovy, just right click the application run as --> Groovy Console. It will execute the application in groovy.